# How do I decrease first load time in ASP.net MVC 2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-6

I have an ASP.net MVC 2 application that runs well locally. However when I move the files to my production server, I get a first time lag of about 30 seconds, I assume this is a first compile. After that the application works fine. Then after about 20-30 minutes of non use, the applications takes another 30 seconds or so to load.

I did try to precompile the code, but there is still a lag during the first load.

Are there any trick to getting the application to work faster on the first load?

I am using ASP.net 3.5, IIS 6 , visual studio 2010, MVC 2.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to write a Windows Service application to call my pages every 10 minutes, so far it's working well.

Comment: There are some commercial services that will do this for you (some for free, I believe).  It's a double edged sword-- and both sides cut.  if you have enough traffic, you'll never see it.  If you have very little traffic, every visitor will see it.

Answer (score 6):

Scott Gu has a good blog post [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/09/15/auto-start-asp-net-applications-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx)

EDIT:

There is a similar [post here](https://serverfault.com/questions/26865/start-iis-6-0-application-pool-automatically) on serverfault, which might be useful.

Comment: This is good for ASP.NET 4 and IIS 7.5, however I am using ASP.NET 3.5 and IIS6

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the application pool is idle and is automatically shutting down the worker process.  Then, when you try to access the page, it needs to start up the worker process and get everything ready.

If you're running under Server 2003, you can tell it not to shut down the worker process. Benson Yu has a good response here:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1307768/2666610.aspx

Essentially, go to IIS manager, find your asp.net 3.5 application pool that hosts your application, and modify it's performance properties to either not shut down the worker process, or to have a longer timeout.

Comment: its a shared environment and I have no controll over iiS